# Single polygon shapefile to multiple polygon shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, polygon

I created a single shapefile that contains multiple polygons by selection by location of the route I had and the ESRI USA counties polygon layer to give me the counties that were in the area I was interested in.

I want to know if there is a tool to use that can take that new shapefile I created of only the new polygons in my area of interest into an individual shapefile for each county.  So say there were 25 counties that crossed my route, I'd like to have a quick way to get shapefiles individually for each 25 counties.

I'm sure there is a quick script for this, but I'm not too familiar with scripts didn't know if there was quick easy way for this than exporting each individually into shapefiles.

I'm also using ArcMap 10.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an iterator in your model, specifically the [Iterate Feature Selection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00400000000s000000) iterator, then use [Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000) to output each feature to it's own feature class.

Your model will look something like this:

[image]

The element called **Value** temporarily stores the name of the current feature in the iterator.

I've also added a variable for a **Folder** called **OutputFolder** that points to a folder path on my drive.

Here's how you use both the variables in the output of copy features:

[image]

And here's what the folder of outputs looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you mapBaker that is exactly what I was looking for!  I couldn't find the Copy Feature tool, but finally found it. Save so much time

Comment: @Pete great!!! Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

[Split Layers by Attributes](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14127) check out this python toolbox. Split Layer by Attributes, county being the attribute you want

Comment: In the Arctoolbox I just see the tool Mulipart to Singlepart, not the singlepart to multipart.  I'm in the data management toolbox>Featuures toolbox

Comment: I don't think this is the right tool, I'm trying to get a shapefile for each county in my attribute table, which is close to 25 counties

Comment: do you have a shapefile that is all of these 25 counties combined?

Comment: Yes they are all in one shapefile. Trying to get those into single shapefiles in a quick way

Comment: http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14127 check out this python toolbox. Split Layer by Attributes, county being the attribute you want